# Json Array within array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm fetching data from a server. The output is in JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',  
    data: ({category : inpval}),
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'php/projects.php',
    success: function(data) {
       for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          $('#project-grid').append('<p>' + data[i].project + '</p><img src="img/'+data[i].images+'">');
       }
    }
});
```

But data[i].images return an array:

```
image01.jpg,image01a.jpg,image02.jpg
```

How I loop this array inside the main array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you don't want to call `append()` multiple times. It slows things down. It's better practice to create your HTML and append it all in one go.

```
var toAppend = '', images;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  toAppend += '<li><p>'+ data[i].project +'</p>';
  images = data[i].images.split(',');
  for(var j = 0; j < images.length; j++){
    toAppend += '<img src="img/'+images[j]+'" />';
  }
  toAppend += '</li>';
}
$('#project-grid').append(toAppend);
```

Comment: This script is not returning any data.

Comment: @user3004794 - you're right, I was resetting my variables in each loop. I've updated it now to `+=` instead of `=`.

Comment: Great. Now I can see the project name. But the script split each word of image name in one image: <img src="img/i">

Comment: Are you sure `data[i].images` is an array?

Comment: Yes. See console.log(data) extract: alturas: "328,328,370"
cliente: "3"
descricao: "descrição do projeto 4"
id_projeto: "4"
images: "image01.jpg,image01a.jpg,image02.jpg"
larguras: "451,451,944"
project: "Projeto 4"
thumb: "thumb02.jpg"

Comment: Ah, the others were right. It's actually a *string*. I've updated my answer above to reflect that.

Comment: Nice! Just another question: #project-grid is an <ul>. How can I insert project name an images inside <li>?

Comment: Updated again. Simply by wrapping the `<li>` element around each (outer) loop.